# Помогите пожалуйста исправить запрос курсора в БД

Tags: android, sqlite

Приветствую. Запрос должен возвращать средние значения двух столбцов за указанный промежуток времени + берутся для расчета только те строки где в столбце имя имеется определенное значение. Время хранится в миллисекундах.
вот сам запрос:

```
public Cursor getAVG (long start, long finish, String name)
{
    return MyDB.query(DB_TABLE_1,
            new String[] {"AVG(" + COLUMN_DATE + ")", "AVG(" + COLUMN_WEIGHT + ")"},
            COLUMN_DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?" + COLUMN_NAME_OF_EXERCISE + " LIKE ?",
            new String[] {String.valueOf(start), String.valueOf(finish), name},
            null, null, null, null);
}
```

Крашится с ошибкой:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "name_of_exercise": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT AVG(date), AVG(weight) FROM tab_1 WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?name_of_exercise LIKE ?
```

Comment: хочу получить среднее значение столбца `date` и `weight` за  период между start и finish для записей где `name_of_exercise` = некоторому входящему значению

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам же даже ошибка говорит, что у вас проблема рядом с `name_of_exercise`, 
после даты должно быть так `" BETWEEN ? AND ? AND " + COLUMN_NAME_OF_EXERCISE + " LIKE ?"`

Comment: спасибо за помощь!  не подумал о том, что нужно еще `AND` добавить перед последним условием

Comment: Там ещё и пробела не было